# Как прочитать содержимое файла

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью JavaScript загрузить список слов из файла в массив. Как я понимаю прочитать напрямую файл нельзя из-за настроек безопасности. Как еще можно загрузить список слов?

Answer (score 1):

## Можно! <sub>Без сервера!</sub>

С помощью [`FileReader` (ссылка на MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Но, конечно, с явного разрешения пользователя (об этом ниже). Вот пример, за авторством многоуважаемого (см. репутацию) [Paolo Moretti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63011/paolo-moretti), взятый [из его ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26298948/2076787):

```js
function readSingleFile(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    displayContents(contents);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.innerHTML = contents;
}

document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Содержимое файла:</h3>
<pre id="file-content"></pre>
```

---

Конечно, есть определённые ограничения на то, **какие** файлы так можно открывать. На данный момент есть два способа (для пользователя) дать доступ к файлу:

- Выбрать файл в `<input>`'е
- Перетащить файл на страницу